# Json encode doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, json

i want to encode a php array to JSON so i can pass it in a image onclick() as an attribute that's why i need htmlspecialcharts;

And then in the js function im trying to use JSON.parse to convert it to a js object so i can use the data of my array.

But i can't parse it since the syntax i'm getting from encoding is not right

the initial php array is :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Bleu' (length=4)
  1 => int 1
  2 => string 'XL' (length=2)
```

I'm using htmlspecialchars(json_encode()) on it and 
the result i need to get is :

```
 jsonTab = '["Bleu",1,"XL"]';
```

But instead after encoding i get :

```
Bleu,1,XL
```

i don't get why the encoding doesn't work right...

code php in wich i create the php array by listing size of each color of the product :

```
$couleurs = $pdo ->getCouleurProduit($id);
     $nbCouleur = count($couleurs);
     $t = 1;
         foreach ($couleurs as $uneCouleur)
         {

             $taille = $pdo ->getTaille($id,$uneCouleur[0]); // renvoie les taille de la couleur
             $nbTaille = count($taille);                     // renvoie le bombrede taille n0 = 1


             ${'couleur'.$t} = array($uneCouleur[0]);       // definie une tableaux nomé "couleurx" avec pour  premier element le libelle de la couleur
             array_push(${'couleur'.$t}, $nbTaille);        // ajoute en second element au tableaux "couleurx" le nombre de taille pour la couleur 

             for ($i = 0; $i < $nbTaille;  $i++ )           // tant que i est inferieur au nombre de taille 
             {
                 array_push(${'couleur'.$t}, $taille[$i][0]); // on ajoute au tableaux "couleurx" le libelle (a [0]) de chaque taille [i] du tableaux $taille

             }
             ${'cl'.$t} = htmlspecialchars(json_encode(${'couleur'.$t})); //on creer une variable clx qui prend la valeur encoder en json du tableau "couleurx" actuel
             $t++;                                                          

         }$couleurs = $pdo ->getCouleurProduit($id);
     $nbCouleur = count($couleurs);
     $t = 1;
         foreach ($couleurs as $uneCouleur)
         {

             $taille = $pdo ->getTaille($id,$uneCouleur[0]); // renvoie les taille de la couleur
             $nbTaille = count($taille);                     // renvoie le bombrede taille n0 = 1


             ${'couleur'.$t} = array($uneCouleur[0]);       // definie une tableaux nomé "couleurx" avec pour  premier element le libelle de la couleur
             array_push(${'couleur'.$t}, $nbTaille);        // ajoute en second element au tableaux "couleurx" le nombre de taille pour la couleur 

             for ($i = 0; $i < $nbTaille;  $i++ )           // tant que i est inferieur au nombre de taille 
             {
                 array_push(${'couleur'.$t}, $taille[$i][0]); // on ajoute au tableaux "couleurx" le libelle (a [0]) de chaque taille [i] du tableaux $taille

             }
             ${'cl'.$t} = htmlspecialchars(json_encode(${'couleur'.$t})); //on creer une variable clx qui prend la valeur encoder en json du tableau "couleurx" actuel
             $t++;                                                          

         }
```

img the php array for attribute

```
$r=1;

         foreach ($couleurs as $uneCouleur)
         {?>
            <img id = "test" src= "./images/<?=${'couleur'.$r}[0]?>.jpg " alt = "lol" onclick="loadTaille(<?php echo ${'cl'.$r} ?>);"/><?php 
            $r++;   //pour chaque couleur du produit on utilise les tableaux couleurx et clx 
         }?>
```

And js file produit.js

```
 function loadTaille(img){

    // var txt = "'[" + img + "]'";
    // var txt = '["Bleu",1,"XL"]';

    var tailles = JSON.parse(img);
    alert (img)

        }
```

Comment: Unsure what you are attempting? `echo htmlspecialchars (json_encode(array("Bleu",1,"XL")));` works fine for me (assuming you want a version of the json you can output in markup?) - if not, you dont want the htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code, so it's difficult to say where exactly you're going wrong, however, here is a simple example that works for the values you posted:

```
$arr = ['Bleu', 1, 'XL'];
echo json_encode($arr);
```

outputs

```
["Bleu",1,"XL"]
```

As an aside, I don't really think you want to use `htmlspecialchars()` when dynamically generating javascript code. The appropriate context there is *not* html (unless you're inlining the javascript in an html attribute, which I assume is not the case here).

### Update:

Now that I see the code you've posted, I believe you can resolve your syntax error by single-quoting the rendered json string in the javascript context.

Change:

```
onclick="loadTaille(<?php echo ${'cl'.$r} ?>);"
```

to:

```
onclick="loadTaille('<?php echo ${'cl'.$r} ?>');"
```

Comment: This works but i need to use htmlspecialchars(json_encode()) and when i do so it outputs this : 

string '[&quot;Bleu&quot;,1,&quot;XL&quot;]' (length=35)

Comment: That is what `htmlspecialchars()` is designed to output. It converts the double quote character into the corresponding html entity i.e. `&quot;`. What are you expecting it to produce? Also, note what I said above about `htmlspecialchars()` probably not being the right thing to use in a javascript context.

Comment: Okay im sorry i thought it was a simple syntax error so here is what im trying to do :

i want to encode a php array to JSON so i can pass it in a image onclick() as an attribute that's why i need htmlspecialcharts;
And then in the js function im trying to use JSON.parse to convert it to a js object so i can use the data of my array.

But i can't parse it since the syntax i'm getting from encoding is not right.

Sorry for my english, will try to edit with code

Comment: If it's going into an `onclick` attribute, then you actually do want it to look like this: `[&quot;Bleu&quot;,1,&quot;XL&quot;]`. And it's not a syntax error. Why don't you post your actual real code in the question and we'll fix it up for you. You'll get your answer fastest that way.

Comment: I think all you need to do is surround `<?php echo ${'cl'.$r} ?>` in single quotes inside the `onclick` handler. Like this: `onclick="loadTaille('<?php echo ${'cl'.$r} ?>');"`

Comment: It works ! 
but i dont get why, will try to understand this.
thanks you for your time and your help !

Comment: @Kyzend It works because `JSON.parse()` expects a string and previously you were passing an object. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. I would also appreciate an upvote. :)

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining, cant upvote before 15 reputation sorry just signed up

Answer (score 0):

there is no obvious reason to use htmlspecialchars().

If you want to display a json string directly inside an html script element:

```
<script>
var js_arr = <?php echo json_encode(['Bleu', 1, 'XL']); ?>;
console.log(js_arr);
</script>
```